# Problem booting from USB w/ Lenovo E495

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

Just got this new laptop and am trying to remove windows and replace with Ubunut 18.04. While doing the setup the installer crashed and now the laptop cannot load into Windows.

If I put the bootable USB in and try to boot from that it says

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi: Not Found
Failed to start MokManager: Not Fond
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed
: Not Found
```

I have tried remaking the startup disk which doesn't help.

The laptop has secure boot turned off and boot set to UEFI/Legacy with UEFI first.

I am not quite sure how to proceed. This is NOT a dual boot, the intention was only linux.

Answer (score 0):

Which tool have you used for creating the USB? Try rufus - always works for me. Also have you tried ubuntu 19.10 or to change USB stick? I have E595 which is very same but 15" and installed Manjaro 18.1.4, Ubuntu 19.10 and now runnning on Mint 19.3 without problems (so many distros, just for testing which mostly fits to me).

Comment: I tried with the startup disk creator, my other laptop has ubuntu. But I'll give rufus a try.